# java was started by returned exit code=13 eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I know this question have been asked multiple times.
But I have tried looking in most of the posted threads. No one could help.

Here is eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Error
[image]

Both eclipse and java are 64 bit.

Can anyone point out where am doing wrong...?

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't the other questions help?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, what ever they have concluded that exists in my settings..! :)

Comment: One thing I read was "make sure the folders don't contain special characters" - then I look at `D:\#kits\...` in your post ...

Comment: @Thomas, Boom Its correct, but could you please share how its causing this issue..?

Comment: This almost always means you are mixing 64 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit. Your Eclipse is 64 bit.

Comment: I can't exactly tell you how that is causing the issue but it might be the [ini-format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) defining the hash character to mark a comment and  `\#` being the escape sequence for that. Hence `D:\#kits\...` might result in either `D:\` (if the rest is assumed to be a comment) or more likely `D:#kits` because `\#` is seen as the escape sequence. You could try using `D:\\\#kits\...`, i.e. have an escaped backslash and an escaped hash.